# How to swap the order of yes no button in alert dialog in android

Tags: android

I used this code to generate alert dialog in android. But i want yes button in the left and no button in the right. How can i do this??

```
AlertDialog.Builder    builder = new    AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext());
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setTitle("Title");
                builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public   void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
```

Comment: replace text and also add event as per your requirement,

Comment: whether it is set negative or positive... you can add your event as you wish. so as Dhaval said you can fire appropriate event on whichever button you want.

Answer (score 2):

you can change the text in positive nagative buttons as your wish and and write what ever code in that.

```
AlertDialog.Builder    builder = new    AlertDialog.Builder(
                            getApplicationContext());
                    builder.setCancelable(true);
                    builder.setTitle("Title");
                    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("No",
                            new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public   void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    builder.setNegativeButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
```